# Multi-domain SAN certificate throwing 'unable to verify the first certificate' error

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, emr, presto

I have a self-signed multi-domain SAN certificate as below :

```
$ openssl x509 -in trustedCertificates.pem -noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            d0:6e:6b:66:c6:55:44:09
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=WA, L=Seattle, O=MyOrg, OU=MyDept, CN=*.us-west-2.compute.internal
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 23 22:15:10 2018 GMT
            Not After : Mar 23 22:15:10 2019 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=WA, L=Seattle, O=MyOrg, OU=MyDept, CN=*.us-west-2.compute.internal
        Subject Public Key Info:
            ...
            ...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         ...
         ...
```

I use this certificate to configure+enable SSL on presto server. Further, I import this certificate in the java truststore of the presto-cli client machine (in my case, both are on same host). However, when I connect to the presto-server, I keep getting the below error message even though I do use a FQDN that matches the CN in the certificate :

```
$ presto-cli --server https://ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal:8446 --catalog hive --schema default --debug --user Administrator --password
Password:
presto:default> show schemas;
Error running command: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal not verified:
    certificate: sha256/zN/GPT/AWTkUAEpAGhhSTvQAmIYPRmLBxvBU6oJDQfM=
    DN: CN=*.us-west-2.compute.internal, OU=MyDept, O=MyOrg, L=Seattle, ST=WA, C=US
    subjectAltNames: [*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com]
...
...
    at com.facebook.presto.cli.Presto.main(Presto.java:32)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal not verified:
    certificate: sha256/zN/GPT/AWTkUAEpAGhhSTvQAmIYPRmLBxvBU6oJDQfM=
    DN: CN=*.us-west-2.compute.internal, OU=MyDept, O=MyOrg, L=Seattle, ST=WA, C=US
    subjectAltNames: [*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:308)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:268)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
    at 
...
...
com.facebook.presto.client.JsonResponse.execute(JsonResponse.java:130)
    ... 7 more
```

When I do a connection check, I see this error :

```
$  openssl s_client -connect ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal:8446
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = US, ST = WA, L = Seattle, O = MyOrg, OU = MyDept, CN = *.us-west-2.compute.internal
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = WA, L = Seattle, O = MyOrg, OU = MyDept, CN = *.us-west-2.compute.internal
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=WA/L=Seattle/O=MyOrg/OU=MyDept/CN=*.us-west-2.compute.internal
   i:/C=US/ST=WA/L=Seattle/O=MyOrg/OU=MyDept/CN=*.us-west-2.compute.internal
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
...
```

If I use a certificate with only single domain CN=*.us-west-2.compute.internal without any SAN extension, everything seem to be working fine. Any ideas on what's going wrong here?

Comment: An idea : your Java version. It should be 1.8.0_141 minimum.

Comment: If cert contains SAN, CN is ignored and host from URL must match SAN -- see rfc 2818. If SAN is `something.amazonaws.com`  (only) but URL host is `something.internal` then that cert is invalid for that host.

Comment: `openssl s_client` doesn't use the Java truststore. Extract or copy the cert to a PEM file and provide it to s_client with `-CAfile`. But s_client (and libssl) only does chain validation; it doesn't do hostname verification at all until 1.1.0 and then not by default.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 the question mentions this Exception : javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Comment: @EugèneAdell $ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_161"

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Ah I see! In that case, would multiple wildcard domain names in the SAN help solve the issue? Something like - 

DNS:*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
DNS:*.us-west-2.compute.internal

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I tried referring the PEM file already but still get the same error : $  openssl s_client -connect ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal:8446 -CAfile trustedCertificates.pem

Comment: (1) Yes if you need to access a TLS server using two or more names (not differing in only the first 'label') put them both/all in SAN. Or else use vhosts with different certs; I don't know if that's an option for AWS. (2) s_client -CAfile should work, but you don't give enough info to try to reproduce. This appears to be a side issue, but if you want to pursue it change your Q to include testable details. And probably version/build info, although I don't recall any version dependency for explicit CAfile (there were for implicit, and for the hashing in CApath).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I think your suggestion (1) did the magic. Thank you!